# Angular2 Multiple router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an issue with my application. I need that hierarchy(see hierarchy picture link) and display my SettingsComponents under DashboardComponent :

[Hierarchy picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQAeR.png)

Here my [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/fKdGL24cmIkygw3zhHKu)

I tried to name my router-outlet with :

`<router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>`

and change the routerLink but he doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you describe the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: @ani5ha On the Dashboard, i need to display under "Need Component here:" the links content. ( When i click in setting profile link -> The SettingsComponent view must be display under Need component here:" ) Thanks a lot.

Comment: found the solution : https://plnkr.co/edit/moMbEuKRhkY8mf8kzExX?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/moMbEuKRhkY8mf8kzExX?p=preview

```
{path: '', component: DashboardComponent, 
    children: [
            {
                path:'settings', loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule' 
            }
    ]
}
```

Have made a mistake on DashboardRouting, i must declare The SettingsComponent as children.